# OpenGL display is not working without GPU on Mac?

Tags: docker, macos, terminal, ros, glx

I am very new to ROS simulations. So I need to run the existing project with Docker on Mac. I get the following error from glxgears:

```
~/catkin_ws$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
libGL: MESA-LOADER: dlopen(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/agilicious/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/agilicious/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I do not have a GPU so how can I make it work without GPU?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?